# Python: Get specific values from a huge JSON and storing it as Lists

Tags: python, json, list

This prints all the districts for a given state from https://api.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json, How do I get the all the districts in the json without specifying the state name. And I want them as a list

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import json
import requests

url= 'https://api.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json' 
r = urllib.request.urlopen(url) 
data = r.read().decode() 
js = json.loads(data) 

n = "Andaman and Nicobar Islands"       # n is state name
for i in js[n]['districtData']:
    print(i)
```

Basically I want, lst = [Nicobars, North and Middle Andaman,South Andaman,Unknown,Foreign Evacuees,Anantapur,Chittoor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests


r = requests.get("https://api.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json").json()

districts = []
for i in r.values():
    for k in i['districtData'].keys():
        districts.append(k)
print(districts)
```

Or if you prefer list comprehension:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://api.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json").json()
print([k for i in r.values() for k in i['districtData'].keys()])
```

Output:

```
['Unassigned', 'Nicobars', 'North and Middle Andaman', 'South Andaman', 'Unknown', 'Foreign Evacuees', 'Anantapur', 'Chittoor', 'East Godavari', 'Guntur', 'Krishna', 'Kurnool', 'Other State', 'Prakasam', 'S.P.S. Nellore', 'Srikakulam', 'Visakhapatnam', 'Vizianagaram', 'West Godavari', 'Y.S.R. Kadapa', 'Anjaw', 'Changlang', 'East Kameng', 'East Siang', 'Kamle', 'Kra Daadi', 'Kurung Kumey', 'Lepa Rada', 'Lohit', 'Longding', 'Lower Dibang Valley', 'Lower Siang', 'Lower Subansiri', 'Namsai', 'Pakke Kessang', 'Papum Pare', 'Shi Yomi', 'Siang', 'Tawang', 'Tirap', 'Upper Dibang Valley', 'Upper Siang', 'Upper Subansiri', 'West Kameng', 'West Siang', 'Unknown', 'Airport Quarantine', 'Baksa', 'Barpeta', 'Biswanath', 'Bongaigaon', 'Cachar', 'Charaideo', 'Chirang', 'Darrang', 'Dhemaji', 'Dhubri', 'Dibrugarh', 'Dima Hasao', 'Goalpara', 'Golaghat', 'Hailakandi', 'Hojai', 'Jorhat', 'Kamrup', 'Kamrup Metropolitan', 'Karbi Anglong', 'Karimganj', 'Kokrajhar', 'Lakhimpur', 'Majuli', 'Morigaon', 'Nagaon', 'Nalbari', 'Other State', 'Sivasagar', 'Sonitpur', 'South Salmara Mankachar', 'Tinsukia', 'Udalguri', 'West Karbi Anglong', 'Unknown', 'Araria', 'Arwal', 'Aurangabad', 'Banka', 'Begusarai', 'Bhagalpur', 'Bhojpur', 'Buxar', 'Darbhanga', 'East Champaran', 'Gaya', 'Gopalganj', 'Jamui', 'Jehanabad', 'Kaimur', 'Katihar', 'Khagaria', 'Kishanganj', 'Lakhisarai', 'Madhepura', 'Madhubani', 'Munger', 'Muzaffarpur', 'Nalanda', 'Nawada', 'Patna', 'Purnia', 'Rohtas', 'Saharsa', 'Samastipur', 'Saran', 'Sheikhpura', 'Sheohar', 'Sitamarhi', 'Siwan', 'Supaul', 'Vaishali', 'West Champaran', 'Chandigarh', 'Other State', 'Balod', 'Baloda Bazar', 'Balrampur', 'Bametara', 'Bastar', 'Bijapur', 'Bilaspur', 'Dakshin Bastar Dantewada', 'Dhamtari', 'Durg', 'Gariaband', 'Janjgir Champa', 'Jashpur', 'Kabeerdham', 'Kondagaon', 'Korba', 'Koriya', 'Mahasamund', 'Mungeli', 'Narayanpur', 'Raigarh', 'Raipur', 'Rajnandgaon', 'Sukma', 'Surajpur', 'Surguja', 'Uttar Bastar Kanker', 'Gaurela Pendra Marwahi', 'Central Delhi', 'East Delhi', 'New Delhi', 'North Delhi', 'North East Delhi', 'North West Delhi', 'Shahdara', 'South Delhi', 'South East Delhi', 'South West Delhi', 'West Delhi', 'Unknown', 'Other State', 'Dadra and Nagar Haveli', 'Daman', 'Diu', 'Other State', 'North Goa', 'South Goa', 'Unknown', 'Other State', 'Ahmedabad', 'Amreli', 'Anand', 'Aravalli', 'Banaskantha', 'Bharuch', 'Bhavnagar', 'Botad', 'Chhota Udaipur', 'Dahod', 'Dang', 'Devbhumi Dwarka', 'Gandhinagar', 'Gir Somnath', 'Jamnagar', 'Junagadh', 'Kheda', 'Kutch', 'Mahisagar', 'Mehsana', 'Morbi', 'Narmada', 'Navsari', 'Panchmahal', 'Patan', 'Porbandar', 'Rajkot', 'Sabarkantha', 'Surat', 'Surendranagar', 'Tapi', 'Vadodara', 'Valsad', 'Bilaspur', 'Chamba', 'Hamirpur', 'Kangra', 'Kinnaur', 'Kullu', 'Lahaul and Spiti', 'Mandi', 'Shimla', 'Sirmaur', 'Solan', 'Una', 'Foreign Evacuees', 'Ambala', 'Bhiwani', 'Charkhi Dadri', 'Faridabad', 'Fatehabad', 'Gurugram', 'Hisar', 'Italians', 'Jhajjar', 'Jind', 'Kaithal', 'Karnal', 'Kurukshetra', 'Mahendragarh', 'Nuh', 'Palwal', 'Panchkula', 'Panipat', 'Rewari', 'Rohtak', 'Sirsa', 'Sonipat', 'Yamunanagar', 'Bokaro', 'Chatra', 'Deoghar', 'Dhanbad', 'Dumka', 'East Singhbhum', 'Garhwa', 'Giridih', 'Godda', 'Gumla', 'Hazaribagh', 'Jamtara', 'Khunti', 'Koderma', 'Latehar', 'Lohardaga', 'Pakur', 'Palamu', 'Ramgarh', 'Ranchi', 'Sahibganj', 'Saraikela-Kharsawan', 'Simdega', 'West Singhbhum', 'Anantnag', 'Bandipora', 'Baramulla', 'Budgam', 'Doda', 'Ganderbal', 'Jammu', 'Kathua', 'Kishtwar', 'Kulgam', 'Kupwara', 'Mirpur', 'Muzaffarabad', 'Pulwama', 'Punch', 'Rajouri', 'Ramban', 'Reasi', 'Samba', 'Shopiyan', 'Srinagar', 'Udhampur', 'Bagalkote', 'Ballari', 'Belagavi', 'Bengaluru Rural', 'Bengaluru Urban', 'Bidar', 'Chamarajanagara', 'Chikkaballapura', 'Chikkamagaluru', 'Chitradurga', 'Dakshina Kannada', 'Davanagere', 'Dharwad', 'Gadag', 'Hassan', 'Haveri', 'Kalaburagi', 'Kodagu', 'Kolar', 'Koppal', 'Mandya', 'Mysuru', 'Other State', 'Raichur', 'Ramanagara', 'Shivamogga', 'Tumakuru', 'Udupi', 'Uttara Kannada', 'Vijayapura', 'Yadgir', 'Other State', 'Alappuzha', 'Ernakulam', 'Idukki', 'Kannur', 'Kasaragod', 'Kollam', 'Kottayam', 'Kozhikode', 'Malappuram', 'Palakkad', 'Pathanamthitta', 'Thiruvananthapuram', 'Thrissur', 'Wayanad', 'Kargil', 'Leh', 'Unknown', 'Lakshadweep', 'Ahmednagar', 'Akola', 'Amravati', 'Aurangabad', 'Beed', 'Bhandara', 'Buldhana', 'Chandrapur', 'Dhule', 'Gadchiroli', 'Gondia', 'Hingoli', 'Jalgaon', 'Jalna', 'Kolhapur', 'Latur', 'Mumbai', 'Mumbai Suburban', 'Nagpur', 'Nanded', 'Nandurbar', 'Nashik', 'Osmanabad', 'Other State', 'Palghar', 'Parbhani', 'Pune', 'Raigad', 'Ratnagiri', 'Sangli', 'Satara', 'Sindhudurg', 'Solapur', 'Thane', 'Wardha', 'Washim', 'Yavatmal', 'East Garo Hills', 'East Jaintia Hills', 'East Khasi Hills', 'North Garo Hills', 'Ribhoi', 'South Garo Hills', 'South West Garo Hills', 'South West Khasi Hills', 'West Garo Hills', 'West Jaintia Hills', 'West Khasi Hills', 'Unknown', 'CAPF Personnel', 'Bishnupur', 'Chandel', 'Churachandpur', 'Imphal East', 'Imphal West', 'Jiribam', 'Kakching', 'Kamjong', 'Kangpokpi', 'Noney', 'Pherzawl', 'Senapati', 'Tamenglong', 'Tengnoupal', 'Thoubal', 'Ukhrul', 'Unknown', 'Agar Malwa', 'Alirajpur', 'Anuppur', 'Ashoknagar', 'Balaghat', 'Barwani', 'Betul', 'Bhind', 'Bhopal', 'Burhanpur', 'Chhatarpur', 'Chhindwara', 'Damoh', 'Datia', 'Dewas', 'Dhar', 'Dindori', 'Guna', 'Gwalior', 'Harda', 'Hoshangabad', 'Indore', 'Jabalpur', 'Jhabua', 'Katni', 'Khandwa', 'Khargone', 'Mandla', 'Mandsaur', 'Morena', 'Narsinghpur', 'Neemuch', 'Niwari', 'Other Region', 'Panna', 'Raisen', 'Rajgarh', 'Ratlam', 'Rewa', 'Sagar', 'Satna', 'Sehore', 'Seoni', 'Shahdol', 'Shajapur', 'Sheopur', 'Shivpuri', 'Sidhi', 'Singrauli', 'Tikamgarh', 'Ujjain', 'Umaria', 'Vidisha', 'Aizawl', 'Champhai', 'Hnahthial', 'Khawzawl', 'Kolasib', 'Lawngtlai', 'Lunglei', 'Mamit', 'Saiha', 'Saitual', 'Serchhip', 'Others', 'Dimapur', 'Kiphire', 'Kohima', 'Longleng', 'Mokokchung', 'Mon', 'Peren', 'Phek', 'Tuensang', 'Wokha', 'Zunheboto', 'State Pool', 'Others', 'Angul', 'Balangir', 'Balasore', 'Bargarh', 'Bhadrak', 'Boudh', 'Cuttack', 'Deogarh', 'Dhenkanal', 'Gajapati', 'Ganjam', 'Jagatsinghpur', 'Jajpur', 'Jharsuguda', 'Kalahandi', 'Kandhamal', 'Kendrapara', 'Kendujhar', 'Khordha', 'Koraput', 'Malkangiri', 'Mayurbhanj', 'Nabarangapur', 'Nayagarh', 'Nuapada', 'Puri', 'Rayagada', 'Sambalpur', 'Subarnapur', 'Sundargarh', 'Amritsar', 'Barnala', 'Bathinda', 'Faridkot', 'Fatehgarh Sahib', 'Fazilka', 'Ferozepur', 'Gurdaspur', 'Hoshiarpur', 'Jalandhar', 'Kapurthala', 'Ludhiana', 'Mansa', 'Moga', 'Pathankot', 'Patiala', 'Rupnagar', 'S.A.S. Nagar', 'Sangrur', 'Shahid Bhagat Singh Nagar', 'Sri Muktsar Sahib', 'Tarn Taran', 'Karaikal', 'Mahe', 'Puducherry', 'Yanam', 'Ajmer', 'Alwar', 'Banswara', 'Baran', 'Barmer', 'Bharatpur', 'Bhilwara', 'Bikaner', 'BSF Camp', 'Bundi', 'Chittorgarh', 'Churu', 'Dausa', 'Dholpur', 'Dungarpur', 'Evacuees', 'Ganganagar', 'Hanumangarh', 'Italians', 'Jaipur', 'Jaisalmer', 'Jalore', 'Jhalawar', 'Jhunjhunu', 'Jodhpur', 'Karauli', 'Kota', 'Nagaur', 'Other State', 'Pali', 'Pratapgarh', 'Rajsamand', 'Sawai Madhopur', 'Sikar', 'Sirohi', 'Tonk', 'Udaipur', 'East Sikkim', 'North Sikkim', 'South Sikkim', 'West Sikkim', 'Unknown', 'Foreign Evacuees', 'Other State', 'Adilabad', 'Bhadradri Kothagudem', 'Hyderabad', 'Jagtial', 'Jangaon', 'Jayashankar Bhupalapally', 'Jogulamba Gadwal', 'Kamareddy', 'Karimnagar', 'Khammam', 'Komaram Bheem', 'Mahabubabad', 'Mahabubnagar', 'Mancherial', 'Medak', 'Medchal Malkajgiri', 'Mulugu', 'Nagarkurnool', 'Nalgonda', 'Narayanpet', 'Nirmal', 'Nizamabad', 'Peddapalli', 'Rajanna Sircilla', 'Ranga Reddy', 'Sangareddy', 'Siddipet', 'Suryapet', 'Vikarabad', 'Wanaparthy', 'Warangal Rural', 'Warangal Urban', 'Yadadri Bhuvanagiri', 'Unknown', 'Railway Quarantine', 'Airport Quarantine', 'Other State', 'Ariyalur', 'Chengalpattu', 'Chennai', 'Coimbatore', 'Cuddalore', 'Dharmapuri', 'Dindigul', 'Erode', 'Kallakurichi', 'Kancheepuram', 'Kanyakumari', 'Karur', 'Krishnagiri', 'Madurai', 'Nagapattinam', 'Namakkal', 'Nilgiris', 'Perambalur', 'Pudukkottai', 'Ramanathapuram', 'Ranipet', 'Salem', 'Sivaganga', 'Tenkasi', 'Thanjavur', 'Theni', 'Thiruvallur', 'Thiruvarur', 'Thoothukkudi', 'Tiruchirappalli', 'Tirunelveli', 'Tirupathur', 'Tiruppur', 'Tiruvannamalai', 'Vellore', 'Viluppuram', 'Virudhunagar', 'Dhalai', 'Gomati', 'Khowai', 'North Tripura', 'Sipahijala', 'South Tripura', 'Unokoti', 'West Tripura', 'Agra', 'Aligarh', 'Ambedkar Nagar', 'Amethi', 'Amroha', 'Auraiya', 'Ayodhya', 'Azamgarh', 'Baghpat', 'Bahraich', 'Ballia', 'Balrampur', 'Banda', 'Barabanki', 'Bareilly', 'Basti', 'Bhadohi', 'Bijnor', 'Budaun', 'Bulandshahr', 'Chandauli', 'Chitrakoot', 'Deoria', 'Etah', 'Etawah', 'Farrukhabad', 'Fatehpur', 'Firozabad', 'Gautam Buddha Nagar', 'Ghaziabad', 'Ghazipur', 'Gonda', 'Gorakhpur', 'Hamirpur', 'Hapur', 'Hardoi', 'Hathras', 'Jalaun', 'Jaunpur', 'Jhansi', 'Kannauj', 'Kanpur Dehat', 'Kanpur Nagar', 'Kasganj', 'Kaushambi', 'Kushinagar', 'Lakhimpur Kheri', 'Lalitpur', 'Lucknow', 'Maharajganj', 'Mahoba', 'Mainpuri', 'Mathura', 'Mau', 'Meerut', 'Mirzapur', 'Moradabad', 'Muzaffarnagar', 'Pilibhit', 'Pratapgarh', 'Prayagraj', 'Rae Bareli', 'Rampur', 'Saharanpur', 'Sambhal', 'Sant Kabir Nagar', 'Shahjahanpur', 'Shamli', 'Shrawasti', 'Siddharthnagar', 'Sitapur', 'Sonbhadra', 'Sultanpur', 'Unnao', 'Varanasi', 'Almora', 'Bageshwar', 'Chamoli', 'Champawat', 'Dehradun', 'Haridwar', 'Nainital', 'Pauri Garhwal', 'Pithoragarh', 'Rudraprayag', 'Tehri Garhwal', 'Udham Singh Nagar', 'Uttarkashi', 'Alipurduar', 'Bankura', 'Birbhum', 'Cooch Behar', 'Dakshin Dinajpur', 'Darjeeling', 'Hooghly', 'Howrah', 'Jalpaiguri', 'Jhargram', 'Kalimpong', 'Kolkata', 'Malda', 'Murshidabad', 'Nadia', 'North 24 Parganas', 'Other State', 'Paschim Bardhaman', 'Paschim Medinipur', 'Purba Bardhaman', 'Purba Medinipur', 'Purulia', 'South 24 Parganas', 'Uttar Dinajpur']
```

To get the district data just use a list of dicts.

For example:

```
districts = []
for i in r.values():
    for k, v in i['districtData'].items():
        districts.append({k: v})
print(districts)
```

With list comprehension:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://api.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json").json()
print([{k: v} for i in r.values() for k, v in i['districtData'].items()])
```

Output:

```
{'Unassigned': {'notes': '', 'active': 0, 'confirmed': 0, 'deceased': 0, 'recovered': 0, 'delta': {'confirmed': 0, 'deceased': 0, 'recovered': 0}}}, {'Nicobars': {'notes': 'District-wise numbers are out-dated as cumulative counts for each district are not reported in bulletin', 'active': 0, 'confirmed': 0, 'deceased': 0, 'recovered': 0, 'delta': {'confirmed': 0, 'deceased': 0, 'recovered': 0}}}, {'North and Middle Andaman': {'notes': 'District-wise numbers are out-dated as cumulative counts for each district are not reported in bulletin', 'active': 0, 'confirmed': 1, 'deceased': 0, 'recovered': 1, 'delta': {'confirmed': 0, 'deceased': 0, 'recovered': 0}}},
...
```

To get all the values per key from each district, just substitue the key name:

*Note: I'm using `confirmed` as an example, you can get all the other values the same way*

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://api.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json").json()
print([v['confirmed'] for i in r.values() for v in i['districtData'].values()])
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 1, 51, 3579, 434, 52298, 54059, 85247, 48864, 23591, 53754, 2461, 40826, 47283, 35468, 46508, 30978, 56741, 39264, 91, 636, 252, 438, 3, 4, 23, 83, 198, 94, 168, 152, 147, 216, 32, 2678, 21, 44, 243, 232, 4, 108, 173, 460, 351, 154, 13, 687, 1121, 467, 1303, 6111, 113, 280, 1967, 765, 1723, 8653, 237, 658, 2896, 1632, 1646, 6519, 4590, 39220, 632, 1200, 408, 2449, 165, 638, 4515, 948, 1, 529, 2351, 51, 3366, 758, 39, 54207, 4681, 1639, 3434, 2128, 6029, 6950, 3971, 3272, 2918, 6070, 5313, 3699, 1991, 2725, 1502, 5356, 2568, 2771, 2402, 2805, 5706, 2734, 7405, 5428, 2536, 25356, 5395, 5023, 4473, 3936, 5156, 2090, 977, 3198, 3435, 3547, 3932, 4436, 9516, 143, 1489, 2156, 674, 940, 2035, 1234, 5834, 1087, 1401, 7766, 978, 3295, 832, 1532, 890, 1995, 1117, 1623, 973, 1023, 4662, 26119, 6340, 1106, 1087, 1681, 1338, 267, 184, 38, 37, 60, 25, 32, 48, 70, 130, 42, 122, 238040, 0, 1389, 1184, 287, 200, 2668, 3511, 21000, 162, 34581, 1773, 968, 521, 1566, 1969, 3677, 655, 440, 1508, 93, 455, 3146, 1235, 4795, 2377, 1148, 1750, 817, 2131, 1385, 813, 1077, 1995, 1473, 397, 7421, 919, 25668, 1500, 507, 10462, 1114, 598, 677, 762, 1759, 138, 433, 96, 1228, 826, 1482, 2566, 1057, 0, 6690, 2301, 481, 17270, 1827, 17077, 4479, 0, 2084, 1578, 1996, 6291, 4416, 2797, 1021, 2191, 4765, 6372, 4840, 4771, 2846, 6889, 3279, 3210, 1079, 2034, 4339, 854, 11911, 1674, 2857, 1085, 1423, 2854, 657, 1220, 2468, 1331, 905, 604, 2211, 3115, 14955, 1150, 2332, 1485, 2825, 3151, 3083, 3726, 4217, 1350, 2410, 9650, 1619, 792, 2154, 3079, 0, 0, 3413, 1239, 1923, 969, 701, 1296, 1916, 12637, 1716, 8987, 28485, 17559, 7343, 187705, 5723, 3354, 6290, 6925, 5779, 19322, 14243, 15309, 7900, 13229, 7366, 15333, 2177, 4887, 9834, 8907, 28677, 36, 10164, 4583, 13572, 10591, 14891, 7941, 8365, 7505, 0, 9332, 10667, 2640, 7348, 8004, 8169, 7124, 10688, 14511, 7348, 5421, 24699, 8007, 2425, 1581, 2054, 0, 0, 33890, 5946, 10103, 31402, 8257, 3671, 6117, 7103, 11434, 1454, 4087, 2343, 41373, 6459, 36076, 14043, 180668, 0, 60109, 12777, 4450, 60650, 9959, 1221, 33005, 4512, 253554, 45135, 7100, 29769, 28518, 2931, 30191, 166982, 2653, 3236, 6318, 107, 308, 2745, 32, 377, 38, 27, 8, 605, 41, 68, 91, 1384, 317, 118, 486, 889, 2178, 148, 228, 159, 349, 77, 33, 272, 270, 84, 866, 315, 434, 327, 894, 664, 366, 667, 1586, 1374, 770, 14339, 662, 972, 859, 1257, 1057, 1079, 1706, 342, 571, 8720, 704, 1087, 18717, 7151, 1103, 882, 1267, 2762, 446, 1304, 2379, 1615, 1688, 276, 0, 481, 1046, 1113, 1661, 1354, 1830, 1065, 1260, 533, 1242, 756, 721, 1822, 593, 585, 622, 2455, 338, 1388, 1032, 17, 5, 4, 210, 34, 141, 34, 31, 11, 29, 46, 2670, 16, 1660, 7, 44, 333, 351, 34, 75, 35, 121, 2738, 0, 2544, 3397, 6067, 5123, 4334, 1369, 15485, 479, 2983, 3324, 19567, 3771, 6678, 3089, 2464, 3385, 3755, 3293, 30145, 5347, 3051, 6436, 2684, 4120, 2025, 7913, 6699, 4730, 2264, 6291, 7728, 1592, 4646, 2281, 1652, 1684, 2716, 4752, 3527, 10976, 2481, 15715, 1233, 1961, 2627, 9963, 1587, 8144, 3067, 1162, 1968, 1344, 1603, 140, 18727, 1443, 5793, 9535, 1011, 1139, 2562, 4027, 2901, 5514, 85, 1088, 1385, 1380, 760, 2637, 1419, 61, 1074, 682, 2, 16741, 648, 1625, 2194, 1340, 16399, 731, 8224, 3058, 189, 4805, 686, 1554, 751, 3459, 1632, 939, 3260, 1446, 1, 475, 87, 294, 33, 250, 1400, 3098, 57598, 3185, 1944, 1098, 2261, 3217, 7203, 5010, 728, 2871, 2800, 2850, 1936, 9716, 1116, 2141, 5944, 635, 1248, 5066, 3304, 2531, 13969, 4544, 3918, 3657, 1056, 1846, 1888, 6766, 1885, 457, 428, 1833, 0, 3411, 31972, 153616, 24778, 17568, 2554, 8230, 5116, 8506, 20205, 11547, 2448, 3538, 15724, 4555, 3898, 2750, 1622, 7962, 5332, 12519, 15923, 4701, 6638, 9063, 14112, 29664, 5883, 12710, 9363, 11620, 4119, 5727, 13949, 13274, 10121, 13929, 2176, 2505, 1462, 1783, 2364, 1795, 1390, 8029, 4595, 7118, 1267, 2121, 2308, 1881, 5070, 4097, 1193, 2775, 5216, 1364, 1626, 5495, 9087, 3166, 1437, 2593, 2404, 3226, 2803, 1056, 5321, 1535, 3451, 2001, 1970, 2318, 11043, 12022, 3535, 3331, 13545, 910, 2323, 3885, 871, 1925, 4565, 6263, 2184, 1603, 21962, 1264, 1319, 4349, 3873, 2162, 44109, 4223, 715, 2441, 3516, 2113, 7507, 2129, 7370, 3798, 3154, 3035, 15972, 2373, 4462, 6251, 2036, 2360, 4908, 1979, 856, 2862, 3137, 2425, 2834, 3014, 11781, 1035, 511, 681, 602, 9609, 7798, 4802, 1322, 831, 548, 1830, 6943, 1495, 3725, 4409, 3072, 4703, 4776, 6814, 10903, 16043, 5151, 489, 732, 49070, 6029, 4874, 5986, 44184, 66, 5939, 8169, 4058, 9196, 2624, 14731, 3029]
```

Comment: This works thanks, Do you know if I can get associated data as well, i.e confirmed, active...

Comment: @Sumukhjadhav I've udpated the answer.

Comment: No, that answer was right. I just wanted to know if I can extract those in a separate list, like all the active cases in one list and so on. Just the data like active = [0, 3283, 7823..],
Trying to pass it into a DB so

Comment: @Sumukhjadhav sure you can. See the udpate.

Answer (score 1):

The data is already in in `json` format,
You just have to do some dictionary manipulation

```
import requests

url = r"https://api.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json"
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()

all_districts = []

for key, value in data.items():
    # value is district data
    for key1 in value["districtData"]:
        all_districts.append(key1)

print(all_districts)
```